# Python : can't solve AttributeError - object has no attribute xxx

Tags: python

This is the python code that causes me problems :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class ObjectType2 (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.name = ""
        self.value2 = 0


class ObjectType1 (object):
    def __init (self):
        self.value = 0
        self.variables = []


class MainStruct (object):

    def __init__ (self):
        index1 = 0
        index2 = 0
        self.objects1 = []
        for index1 in [0, 1, 2]:
            self.objects1.append(ObjectType1())
            self.objects1[index1].value = index1
            self.objects1[index1].variables.append(ObjectType2())



if __name__ == '__main__':

    foobar = MainStruct()
    for x in foobar.objects1:
        print(x.value)
```

When I execute it, I've got the folowing error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Franck\Documents\Developpement\python\dbc_file_reader \test1.py", line 31, in <module>
    foobar = MainStruct()
  File "C:\Users\Franck\Documents\Developpement\python\dbc_file_reader\test1.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.objects1[index1].variables.append(ObjectType2())
AttributeError: 'ObjectType1' object has no attribute 'variables'
```

It looks like it's related to the empty list initialisation in ObjectType1, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Could somebody point me out where is the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
def __init (self):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self):
          ↑↑
```

Without the two trailing underscores this is just a method like any other, not a constructor.

Comment: Oops ! Thanks for the answer. I spent literally hours searching for a solution, and it was a f****** typo !! Shame on me...